# How to create SignalR groups from Blazor app

Tags: .net-core, signalr, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a (serverside) blazor app and I want to let users fill in a small form and press a button to create SignalR groups that they can then send messages to.

I have a Hub class that looks like this:

```cs
public class RoomHub : Hub
{
    public async Task JoinRoomAsync(string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public async Task LeaveRoomAsync(string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public async Task BroadcastToRoomAsync(string groupName, string message)
    {
        await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("OnMessage", message);
    }
}
```

and a Service class that gets called from my blazor component, which looks like this:

```cs
public class RoomService : IRoomService
{
    private ICosmosDbService _dbService;
    private RoomHub _roomHub;

    public RoomService(ICosmosDbService dbService, RoomHub roomHub)
    {
        this._dbService = dbService;
        this._roomHub = roomHub;
    }

    public async Task<Room> CreateRoom(string name)
    {
        Room r = new Room();
        r.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        r.Name = name;
        await _dbService.AddItemAsync(r);
        await _roomHub.JoinRoomAsync(r.Name);

        return r;
    }

    public async Task SendToRoom(Room r, string message)
    {
        await _roomHub.BroadcastToRoomAsync(r.Name, message);
        return;
    }
}
```

When I add the `RoomHub` class to my services in `Startup.cs` and run my application, when I press the button to create a Group it tells me the Hub's `Context` variable is null and fails.

I've tried looking around for other ways to do this, and arrived at the conclusion that it has something to do with injecting an `IHubContext<RoomHub>` object instead, but the object this provides does not seem related at all to  my Hub class and I can't use it to create groups directly because I don't have access to the `ConnectionId` I need to do so.

I feel like there's a gap between the Hub and HubContext that I do not understand. What is the correct way to create a SignalR Group, starting from a button press on a Blazor component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you can access your Hub, you need to build and start your Hub connection using `HubConnection` and `HubConnectionBuilder`. This needs to include the url for your Hub and the handler methods for the data received from the Hub.

Start by adding a HubConnection field in your Service class.

```cs
    private HubConnection _hubConnection;
```

Depending on your Service lifetime and other considerations, you can build your connection in the Service class constructor or it's own method. For an example, we'll add a StartConnectionAsync task.

```cs
public async Task StartConnectionAsync()
{
    // Create the connection
    _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(_hubUrl) // _hubUrl is your base Url + Hub Url
    .Build();
    // Add Handler for when a client receives a broadcast message
    _hubConnection.On<string>("OnMessage", this.SomeEventHandler);
    // Then you start the connection
    await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
}
```

Without using a typed Hub, you'll call your Hub methods using magic strings. e.g.

```cs
await _hubConnection.SendAsync("JoinRoomAsync", groupName);
```

This should get you started. Based on what you posted above, I think [this github repo](https://github.com/conficient/blazorchatsample) is similar to what you're intending to do.